# Show one menu element and hide another

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with a flow in my app, which causes the UI to not render the menu items properly.

My flow is as follows: I have a login/logout menu item, which is shown or hidden according to login status.

```
private fun initViewModel() {
    val loginMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.loginFragment)
    val logoutMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
    viewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { isLoggedIn ->
        logoutMenuItem.isVisible = isLoggedIn
         loginMenuItem.isVisible = !isLoggedIn
    })
}
    
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
        
    if (!handled) {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_logout -> {
                 viewModel.logout()
            }
        }
    }
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return handled
}
```

Problem is, when I click on log out, the log in item is never shown properly, instead, the space is empty.

I was able to workaround this with a simple coroutine, but I think this is a bad hack.

```
val loginMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.loginFragment)
val logoutMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
viewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { isLoggedIn ->
    logoutMenuItem.isVisible = isLoggedIn
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        loginMenuItem.isVisible = !isLoggedIn
    }
})
```

What am I missing? It seems very odd to me that when I delay the login menu item showing, it works just fine.
I am using navigation components, if it makes any difference. I tried invalidate() on the navigation view itself, but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, I think this is better than 1s horrendous delay. As I understand, the second isVisible is now called somewhere in the view cycle.

```
val loginMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.loginFragment)
val logoutMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
viewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { isLoggedIn ->
    logoutMenuItem.isVisible = isLoggedIn
    nav_view.post {
        loginMenuItem.isVisible = !isLoggedIn
    }
})
```

Anyway, I suspect a framework bug.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess you forget to set viewModel.isLoggedIn = false when you click
> logout

```
 private fun initViewModel() {
        val loginMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.loginFragment)
        val logoutMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
        viewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { isLoggedIn ->
            logoutMenuItem.isVisible = isLoggedIn
             loginMenuItem.isVisible = !isLoggedIn
        })
    }
        
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            
        if (!handled) {
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_logout -> {
                     viewModel.logout()
                     viewModel.isLoggedIn = false // <------- you should add this also
                }
            }
        }
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return handled
    }
```

> And this should work as normal now

```
private fun initViewModel() {
    val loginMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.loginFragment)
    val logoutMenuItem = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
    viewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { isLoggedIn ->
        logoutMenuItem.isVisible = isLoggedIn
         loginMenuItem.isVisible = !isLoggedIn
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to add that in the viewmodel, I am interacting with the repository and the isLoggedIn is updated correctly. I can also see the observer is called with the correct parameters, it's just the view that is not getting rendered. I suspect it is a framework bug but I am not sure.